# nth derivative of a holomorphic function

Tags: complex-analysis

I am to show that if $f(z)$ is holomorphic within (and on) a circle $C$ with radius $r$ and center $a$, and if $|f(z)|\le M$ for all $z\in\Bbb C$, that the $n$-th derivative of $f$ at $a$ is less than or equal to $Mn!/r^n$

I am trying to achieve the stated relation using Cauchy's generalized integral formula without success:

\begin{align*}
|f^n(a)|
&= |n!/2\pi i  \oint f(z)/(z-a)^n dz| \\
&\le |n!/2\pi i \oint M/(z-a)^n dz|\\
&= |Mn!/2\pi i \oint 1/(z-a)^n dz|
\end{align*}

so from here I need to show 
$$
1/2\pi i \oint \frac1{(z-a)^n} dz \le 1/r^n
$$

Comment: The method _should_ yield the given estimate. To tell why you didn't succeed, can we see what you did?

Comment: First of all, you have a mistake in the formula. It's $$f^{(n)}(a) = \frac{n!}{2\pi i}\int_{\lvert z-a\rvert = r} \frac{f(z)}{(z-a)^{n+1}}\,dz.$$ Then, to get an estimate, you need to take absolute values, inequalities between complex numbers generally don't make sense. The standard estimate (I think $ML$-inequality is also a widespread name) yields the desired inequality.

Comment: yes, sorry the problem had absolute value signs around the derivative I was neglecting them. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3):

If $f$ is holomorphic on $B_{\mathbb C}(a,r[$, and you know that $|f(z)|\leq M\;\;\forall z\in B_{\mathbb C}(a,r]$ then by Cauchy Integral Formula for dervivatives (the one written By Daniel) you have that
$$\begin{align}
|f^{(n)}(a)| &= \left|\frac{n!}{2\pi i}\int_{|\zeta-a|=r}\frac{f(\zeta)}{(\zeta -a)^{n+1}}d\zeta\right|\\
&\leq \frac{n!}{2\pi}\int_{|\zeta-a|=r}\frac{|f(\zeta)|}{|\zeta -a|^{n+1}}\,| d\zeta|\\
&\leq \frac{n!}{2\pi}\int_{|\zeta-a|=r}\frac{M}{r^{n+1}}|d\zeta|\\
&= \frac{n!}{2\pi}\frac{M}{r^{n+1}}\int_{|\zeta-a|=r}|d\zeta|\\
&= \frac{n!}{2\pi}\frac{M}{r^{n+1}}2\pi r=\frac{n!M}{r^n}
\end{align}$$

As requested.